# Sitewide Seal (image) with link back to our site on all our clients

Tags: seo

So a lot of ssl/trust/site scanner providers like comodo, geotrust, symantec, thawte and more always give their clients some code that they usually place in the footer of their websites. This code usually is an image with alt text and sometimes a bit of text that says "Secured by so and so, or powered by so and so".

I have noticed they never have the nofollow tag.

I am about to launch a service which will also allow clients to place a seal on their website. They will most likely be placed in the footer on every page.

I have read that it is best to place a nofollow on footer sitewide links. But most recently i am reading that it is okay to not have the nofollow as long as you only use your brandname and no keywords.

So i am having to decide on what to do. Do i give my clients the code for the image/link with a nofollow or a dofollow?
I can't get a confirmed answered anywhere on which i should do. I would prefer a dofollow, but only if i will not get penalised by google.

Can anyone make any recommendations or information on a good/firm answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score -1):

No Follow, You stated no reason not to, and every reason to do, Google is a 50-50 kind thing, depends whos behind what desk. Stick the safe road.

Comment: Did i say something illogical?

Comment: not sure why someone downvoted that besides you don't really mention anything to say why a nofollow should be used.

Comment: from what i understand it removes it from your "link" tallies, it is better. When it comes to links Quality over Quantity